# Book x++ and loop Java

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I have a question to ask about x++ and loop stuff. First, here is the code:

```
class MixFor5 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int x = 0;
  int y = 30;
  for (int outer = 0; outer < 3; outer++) {

     for(int inner = 4; inner > 1; inner--) {
     x = x++;
     y = y - 2;
         if (x == 6) {
              break;
          }
      x = x + 3;
     }

  y = y - 2;
  }

  System.out.println(x + " " + y);
 }
 }
```

This is how I calculated it:

INNER LOOP

1st loop)  y = -2, then x = 3, end of inner loop

2st loop)  y = -4, x = 6, end of inner loop

3st loop ) y = -6, BREAK, end of inner loop.

Outer loop adds -2 to Y, so y = -8

now we have x = 6, y = 22, but we must go on looping 2 more times. In the inner loop we always get y = -2, then it breaks, because x is still 6, and in outer we aswell get y = -2, which gets us to y = -8 for 2 loops. Add it to what we got (y = -8) , and we get y = -16, adding it to our integer would give us y = 14.

My question is, how does `x++` works in this case? It does nothing here. Is it because of `break;` or because of some other stuff? I thought that it would add +1 to x when inner or outer loop is over, but if you do so, you cannot get the right answer.

Could please anyone explain it?

Comment: Your text is kind of confusing. Wouldn't it help to just print stuff all the time to follow the flow? Try to pinpoint your confusion.

Answer (score 2):

`x = x++;` changes x twice. First it increments it to x+1, and then it assigns to it the previous value. That's why it has no effect - the assignment of the previous value cancels the increment.

Comment: Should be the other way around. First assigns it to itself, then increments.

Comment: No.  If you look at the value before and after, it's the same.  If it incremented after the assignment, it would be one greater after the fact.

Comment: @Distraction No, x++ returns x's old value and then increments it. The assignment takes place only after the completion of the x++ expression.

Comment: for(int inner = 4; inner > 1; inner--) {
     x = x++;
     y = y - 2;
         if (x == 6) {
              break;
          }
      x = x + 3;
     }
how would it work without break here? Would it be like 3, 6 ,9, 12, end of loop and finally x = 13 because of x++  or  would be still 12, and x++ does absolutely nothing in this case?

Comment: Ohh, I get it. Yeah assignment has least precedence. I just find that behavior strange somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Look up post and pre-increment operators.  x++ is a post increment operator, meaning it will increment by one AFTER anything to its left uses its current value.

```
int x = 1; int y;
y = x++; // x==2 and y==1
```

x is being set to its value before it was incremented.  So, nothing changes (in the end).